# Problem with getting a cell value OnRowCommand in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridviewcolumn

```
       protected void GridView1_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

        k = row.Cells[0].ToString();
        Label1.Text = k;
 }
```

I want to get a value of a particular cell in the selected row.So I tried with this but this is giving very odd result the label printing the below text

```
     System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell.
```

Can anybody tell me how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
k = row.Cells[0].Text;
```

You'll get the text present in it.

Answer (score 0):

Use EventHandler Gridview_CellEdit or some similar to this. And then if (selecteditems.count>0) you can get a value of them. With creating a new variable, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Command Argument as

```
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>' CommandName = "QC"
```

And in the RowCommand Event

```
 if (e.CommandName == "QC")            
 {
     int RowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
```

Get the values u want based on the RowIndex.